# Change multiple parameters for Azure MySQL Flexible Server programmatically in bulk

Tags: azure-cli, mysql-5.7

I can change all parameters manually by going to the following page and change them there

[image]

Or I can use *Azure CLI* to change single param:

```bash
az mysql flexible-server parameter set
                --server-name blabla
                --name param_name
                --value param_value
```

But the problem is that there quite a lot of params I would like to change. Is there any way I can change multiple params at once?

Answer (score 1):

- Well according these [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/flexible-server/how-to-configure-server-parameters-cli#code-try-2) there are only two ways of updating the server parameters in azure.
- Which are either through portal or through cli. Now you can update multiple server parameter at once but you will have to enter them manually in the portal.
- Now you through cli the case isn't any different where you can run `az mysql flexible-server parameter set` but it doesn't accept multiple key value pair of the configuration.
- Now the last and only option which remains where you can create a custom script in your desired language where you can generate the new command for each server parameter and run them one by one.